# lvalue required as left operand of assignment for function pointers

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I am trying to assign a function to a function pointer, but I am getting the following error:

> lvalue required as left operand of assignment.

My code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void intr_handler(int param){
    printf("Hey there!\n");
}

int main(){
    void *(intr_handlerptr)(int);
    intr_handlerptr = intr_handler;
}
```

I cannot see what is the problem there, since I am assigning to the pointer "intr_handlerptr" the function "intr_handler" and they have the same signature. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unsure of what `void *(intr_handlerptr)(int);` does (it compiles, though, would be interesting to ask another question for this alone which is now [done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53349871/typo-in-function-pointer-variable-declaration-but-code-compiles)) but this declaration is incorrect. It should be:

```
void (*intr_handlerptr)(int);
```

and then your code compiles properly

tutorial on function pointers: https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html

EDIT: after discussion about this syntax error it seems obvious (now!) that

```
void *(intr_handlerptr)(int);
```

is the same as:

```
void *intr_handlerptr(int);
```

so forward declaring a function (which doesn't exist so it would not link, but you can't see that as the compiler issues an error when trying to assign something to it)

Comment: Whoops, you're right, I think that the instruction I wrote declares a function which returns a pointer to void (maybe?). Thank you for your help :)

Comment: returning a pointer to void would be `void *(*intr_handlerptr)(int);` so 2 stars. No, this isn't that.

Comment: @Stubborn the explanation of the error was indeed very simple. I did not see it :)