# typo in function pointer variable declaration, but code compiles

Tags: c, function-pointers

While answering a [question about function pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53349751/lvalue-required-as-left-operand-of-assignment-for-function-pointers), OP did that to declare a function pointer which takes 1 integer argument and returns nothing:

```
void *(intr_handlerptr)(int);  // wrong but compiles!!
intr_handlerptr = intr_handler;  // compiler error: cannot assign to this weird thing (lvalue required as left operand of assignment)
```

when the proper declaration is

```
void (*intr_handlerptr)(int);  // correct
```

What's funny is that the error occurs when assigning to this function pointer, not when declaring it (tested with gcc 7.3.1)

So what does that first line do?

Comment: That's just a plain old function declaration.

Comment: oh, stupid! of course parentheses are useless, and thus removed, giving: `void *intr_handlerptr(int)`

Comment: At a guess I'd say that the first set of parens (the ones around `intr_handlerptr`) are discarded, making it equivalent to `void *intr_handlerptr(int)`, that is, a simple declaration of a function taking a single `int` that returns a pointer of undefined type (`void *`). You get the error when trying to assign to it because you can't assign to a function symbol.

Comment: yes, that's the explanation. Should the question be removed? someone should answer it or find a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `void *(intr_handlerptr)(int);` reads as "`intr_handlerptr` is a function taking an int and and returning a pointer to an unnamed thing (a void pointer). So the parenthesis around the function name have no use and are discarded. This is a prototype.

The expression `void (*intr_handlerptr)(int);` reads as "`intr_handlerptr` is a pointer to a function taking an int and returning nothing. The parenthesis are necessary to associate the name with the pointer type. This is a variable.

When assigning to the first, the compiler complains that you try to assign to "nothing" because the left-hand symbol is not a variable. Actually, the compiler only knows a prototype of that name in its symbol table. Of course, the second assignment statement is correct because you are assigning to a variable.